# Capitalize first letter of a string (preceded with special characters) - PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'd like to capitalize a string like:

```
¿"hello"?
```

I want my function to return

```
¿"Hello"?
```

I've tried with regex and preg_match, with no luck...
Here it is my previous question, related with this one:
["preg_match is matching two characters when it should only match one"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302582/preg-match-is-matching-two-characters-when-it-should-only-match-one)

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg-replace-callback):

```
preg_replace_callback('/^([^a-z]*)([a-z])/i', function($matches){
    return $matches[1] . strtoupper($matches[2]);
}, '¿"hello"?');

// ¿"Hello"?
```

Comment: This is near the solution, now I think I'm having problems with the regex, because when my string is '¿ésta prueba?', this function returns '¿ésta prueba?' but '¿Ésta prueba?' was expected...

Comment: Here it was the final solution posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133485/using-of-regex-whith-preg-replace-callback/11133597#comment14592579_11133597

Answer (score 2):

Using preg_replace_callback as said ascii-time above, but unicode compatible:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/^(\PL*)(\pL)/u', function($matches){
    return $matches[1] . mb_strtoupper($matches[2],'UTF-8');
}, '¿"éllo"?'),"\n";
```

**output:**

```
¿"Éllo"?
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `ucfirst` function http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

No regex is needed for such task

Sample

```
$foo = 'hello world!';
$foo = ucfirst($foo);             // Hello world!
```