# Regex and accents/tildes

Tags: php, regex, diacritics

How should I include accents into a regex? I'd like to detect letters from `a-z` and `äáàëéèíìöóòúùñç` but this regex doesn't work:

```
$pattern = '/^([a-zäáàëéèíìöóòúùñç])/i';
```

Comment: what language are you working on? can you show an example string you are testing

Comment: My example string could be 'ésta' and I'm working on spanish.. This regex doesn't detect 'é'

Comment: sorry, i meant what programming language.. I don't know why is that 'i' at the end, is it something specific of your programming language?

Comment: Sorry, I included it at the title but I didn't realized it was edited... I'm using PHP, and I don't know what that 'i' means..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the solution to my problem:
[Using of regex whith preg_replace_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133485/using-of-regex-whith-preg-replace-callback/11133597#comment14592579_11133597)
, it seemed the regex has to be like: $pattern = '/(\p{L})(.+)/iu';

Answer (score 3):

You can try using a pre-defined class to match all letters, for instance:

```
[\p{L}]
```

This will work in most regex-engines.

You can read more about unicode in regexes here, for instance: http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: And how could be the usage? I mean, $pattern = '/^([\p{L}])/'; doesn't solve my problem...

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
cat test.php
<?php
preg_match('/\pL/u', 'é', $m);
print_r($m);
?>


php -q test.php
Array
(
    [0] => é
)
```

Comment: Okei, this works in your example, then, what am I doing wrong with this code of a previous question?:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11122274/capitalize-first-letter-of-a-string-preceded-with-special-characters-php
where I write $pattern = '/\pL/u';

Answer (score 1):

You might try to add the `u` flag to your regex (see *PCRE_UTF8* on [modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) page)

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove the last 'i', I'm using [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) to test it and it works without it (and also without the `/` since those are php specific.)

so basically test it in this page like this: `^([a-zäáàëéèíìöóòúùñç])`

Comment: Rubular supplies the slashes (`/`), but you should use the `i` modifier; it makes the match case-insensitive, in Ruby as in PHP.  What the PHP regex is missing is the `u` modifier, which causes the regex and the source string to be treated as UTF-8.