# Why is this php regex not processing accents?

Tags: php, regex

I know this has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123314/regex-and-accents-tildes), but I still can't understand why the following is not working:

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('/(?:[?\p{L}]*\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?/', '$1', 'cafes/123456') . '<br />';
// '123456'

echo preg_replace('/(?:[?\p{L}]*\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?/', '$1', 'cafés/123456') . '<br />';
// 'café123456' where I expect 123456

echo preg_replace('/(?:[?\p{L}é]*\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?/', '$1', 'cafés/123456') . '<br />';
// '123456' thanks to the extra "é" after "\p{L}"
?>
```

Isn't `\p{L}` supposed to replace any accent?

Comment: suggestioN: since your pattern uses `/` internally, you should use some delimeter, such as `#`. This cuts down on the amount of escaping you have to do and gets rid of \/\/\/\/ leaning toothpick syndrome.

Comment: your code displays 123456 three times for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `u` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) that treats strings as UTF-8:

```
echo preg_replace('/(?:[?\p{L}]*\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?/u', '$1', 'cafes/123456') . '<br />';
// '123456'

echo preg_replace('/(?:[?\p{L}]*\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?/u', '$1', 'cafés/123456') . '<br />';
// '123456'

echo preg_replace('/(?:[?\p{L}é]*\/)?(?:[?\w\-]*\/)?/u', '$1', 'cafés/123456') . '<br />';
// '123456'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this one does work for me. I totally missed out on the ``u`` modifier. No idea why it does the opposite for Ondrej...